# Unhandled exception when saving to an already open file in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, savefiledialog

I am trying to write logic for saving a file to local disk in Silverlight 4.0. I am using the `SaveFileDialog` class for that. It works fine. But when I am trying to save to a file that is already opened for viewing, I am getting an unhandled exception. Also the application crashes immediately.

Similar problem was there with Silverlight 3. There I got rid of the issue by swallowing the exception by searching for some `SaveFileStream` text in exceptions, in the application_unhandledexception event. I thought this would be handled in Silverlight 4, but it got worse now. Even the workaround is not working now.

I have put try catch around the `SaveFileDialog` logic and the `IOException` (another process is using file) is safely caught here, but immediately the exception that I described above is triggered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: This happens with excel files and not happening with txt files. I would think this would occur for all MS Office files.

[A post about the issue on the official forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/176869.aspx/1/10?Problem%20disposing%20SaveFileStream%20with%20SaveFileDialog%20when%20error%20opening%20file%20)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with text or excel files. I'm running Silverlight 4.0.60531.0, what are you running? http://www.silverlightversion.com/

Comment: Excel specifically keeps file handles open to stop multiple users modifying a worksheet (unless opened in *readonly* mode). Can you please show the code you are using to swallow the exception?

Answer (score 1):

May I ask you how you save the file?
Is the Stream flushed, closed and disposed properly?

Like this as an example (note : there are lots of alternative says to do this):

```
using (Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("somefilename.ext", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
{
    // Use the stream normally in a TextWriter
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }

    stream.Close();
}
```

Hope it is to and help :-)